# $|X(e^{jω})|^2$ - Power or Energy Density?

Tags: power-spectral-density, dtft

If $x(n)$ is an aperiodic signal and $X(e^{jω})$ its **DTFT**, then, what is $|X(e^{jω})|^2$? Power or Energy Spectral Density? *My understanging of Fourier transforms so far tells me that its energy spectral density and not PSD.*

But, while studying *Spectrum Estimation*, I am getting confused as I am seeing $|X(e^{jω})|^2$ being treated as PSD everywhere. Here is an example -

---

[image]

---

In the above example, $|G_i(e^{jω})|^2$ was treated as PSD, otherwise the relation wouldn't make any sense (at least to me).

I would be grateful if someone could explain. Thank you.

***I don't have problem understanding $P_x(e^{j\omega})$. My problem is only with $|G_i(e^{j\omega})|^2$. How come it's the PSD of $g_i(n)$. Or is it not?***

Answer (score 6):

do you see anywhere in your book where this "**DTFT**" is defined for your w.s.s. process, $x[n]$?  the DTFT is *normally* defined as

$$ X(e^{j \omega}) \triangleq \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n] e^{-j \omega n} $$

but for this infinite sum to converge, we normally require that

$$ \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \Big|x[n]\Big| < +\infty $$

which is a stronger requirement than

$$ \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \Big|x[n]\Big|^2 < +\infty $$

which says simply that the energy of $x[n]$ is finite, and $x[n]$ is a **finite energy signal** or just an **energy signal**.

a **finite power signal** or just a **power signal** does not satisfy the restrictions above, but satisfies this:

$$ \lim_{M \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2M+1} \sum\limits_{n=-M}^{+M} \Big|x[n]\Big|^2 < +\infty $$

sometimes, to do some math, we have to express this a little more strictly as

$$ \lim_{M \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2M+1} \sum\limits_{n=-M}^{+M} \Big|x[n]\Big| < +\infty $$

both restrictions are equivalently true, but the first one is expressing **power** directly.

---

so these "**energy signal**s" and "**power signal**s" live in different **metric spaces**, or more particularly, they live in different **Hilbert spaces**.

Hilbert spaces have something that we call "**inner product**" (or sometimes "**dot product**"):

$$ \big\langle x,y \big\rangle \quad \text{ or } \quad \big\langle x[n],y[n] \big\rangle $$

and we always define the **norm** of $x[n]$ in terms of this inner product:

$$ \big\| x \big\| \triangleq \sqrt{\big\langle x,x \big\rangle}  $$

---

now the inner product for the space of *energy signals* is defined to be:

$$ \big\langle x[n],y[n] \big\rangle \triangleq \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n] \cdot \overline{y[n]} $$

where $\overline{y[n]}$ is the complex conjugate of $y[n]$.  FYI, we see that the inner product is "**conjugate commutative**":

$$ \big\langle x,y \big\rangle = \overline{\big\langle y,x \big\rangle} $$

it should be easy to see that the *norm* $\big\| x \big\|$ is just the square root of the total energy:

$$\begin{align}
 \big\| x \big\|^2 &= \big\langle x,x \big\rangle \\
   &= \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n] \cdot \overline{x[n]} \\
   &= \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \Big|x[n]\Big|^2 \quad < \infty \\
\end{align} $$

---

similarly, the inner product for the space of *power signals* is defined to be:

$$ \big\langle x[n],y[n] \big\rangle \triangleq \lim_{M \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2M+1} \sum\limits_{n=-M}^{+M} x[n] \cdot \overline{y[n]} $$

again, the inner product is *conjugate commutative*:

$$ \big\langle x,y \big\rangle = \overline{\big\langle y,x \big\rangle} $$

and we see that the *norm* $\big\| x \big\|$ is just the square root of the total *power*:

$$\begin{align}
 \big\| x \big\|^2 &= \big\langle x,x \big\rangle \\
   &= \lim_{M \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2M+1} \sum\limits_{n=-M}^{+M} x[n] \cdot \overline{x[n]} \\
   &= \lim_{M \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2M+1} \sum\limits_{n=-M}^{+M} \Big|x[n]\Big|^2 \quad < \infty \\
\end{align} $$

---

now for both energy and power signals, we can define the **cross-correlation** between two signals as:

$$ R_{xy}[m] \triangleq \big\langle x[n+m], y[n] \big\rangle $$

for energy signals it's

$$\begin{align}
 R_{xy}[m] & = \big\langle x[n+m], y[n] \big\rangle \\
     & = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n+m] \cdot \overline{y[n]} \\
\end{align}$$

for power signals it's

$$\begin{align}
 R_{xy}[m] & = \big\langle x[n+m], y[n] \big\rangle \\
     & = \lim_{M \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2M+1} \sum\limits_{n=-M}^{+M} x[n+m] \cdot \overline{y[n]} \\
\end{align}$$

the **autocorrelation** of $x[n]$, denoted $R_{xx}[m]$, is simply the cross-correlation of $x[n]$ with itself

$$ R_{xx}[m] = \big\langle x[n+m], x[n] \big\rangle $$

the **spectral density** is the DTFT of the *autocorrelation*

$$ S_{xx}(e^{j\omega}) = \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} R_{xx}[m] \, e^{-j \omega m} $$

and, more generally, the **cross-spectral density** is the DTFT of the *cross-correlation*

$$ S_{xy}(e^{j\omega}) = \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} R_{xy}[m] \, e^{-j \omega m} $$

---

now, for a deterministic (that means $x[n]$ is known for all $n$) and *finite energy* signal, the DTFT of $x[n]$ is defined

$$ X(e^{j \omega}) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n] e^{-j \omega n} $$

and it can be shown that the spectral density is simply the magnitude-square of the DTFT:

$$ S_{xx}(e^{j\omega}) = \Big| X(e^{j \omega}) \Big|^2 $$

the proof is as

$$\begin{align}
\Big| X(e^{j \omega}) \Big|^2 &= X(e^{j \omega}) \cdot \overline{X(e^{j \omega})} \\
  &= \left( \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n] e^{-j \omega n} \right) \overline{\left( \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n] e^{-j \omega n} \right)} \\
  &= \left( \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n] e^{-j \omega n} \right) \left( \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \overline{x[n] e^{-j \omega n}} \right) \\
  &= \left( \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n] e^{-j \omega n} \right) \left( \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \overline{x[n]} e^{+j \omega n} \right) \\
  &= \left( \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[m] e^{-j \omega m} \right) \left( \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \overline{x[n]} e^{+j \omega n} \right) \\
  &=  \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[m] e^{-j \omega m} \overline{x[n]} e^{+j \omega n} \\
  &=  \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[m] \overline{x[n]} e^{-j \omega (m-n)} \\
  &=  \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n+m] \overline{x[n]} e^{-j \omega (n+m-n)} \\
  &=  \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n+m] \overline{x[n]} \right) e^{-j \omega m} \\
  &=  \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} R_{xx}[m] e^{-j \omega m} \\
  &=  S_{xx}(e^{j \omega}) \\
\end{align}$$

this is the case for a finite *energy signal*.  but for a *power signal*, $x[n]$, the DTFT $X(e^{j \omega})$, does not simply exist without some hand-waving using the dirac delta function $\delta(\omega)$ in the frequency domain, which i do not want to do, and will stay away from that kind of representation.  but the *power spectral density* $S_{xx}(e^{j \omega})$ continues to exist for power signals, even if the DTFT and $\Big|X(e^{j \omega})\Big|^2$ do not.

---

**Filtering**

whether these are both *energy signals* or both *power signals*, with $x[n]$ as input and $y[n]$ as output, a discrete-time LTI system (or "filter") will relate the two with the convolution summation:

$$\begin{align}
 y[n] &= \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} h[m] x[n-m] \\
      &= \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} h[n-m] x[m] \\
\end{align}$$

in the frequency domain, taking the DTFT of both sides is

$$ Y(e^{j \omega}) = H(e^{j \omega}) \cdot X(e^{j \omega}) $$

the impulse response $h[n]$ **must** be a finite energy signal

$$ \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \Big|h[n]\Big|^2 < +\infty $$

and the frequency response $H(e^{j \omega})$ is the DTFT of the impulse response

$$ H(e^{j \omega}) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} h[n] e^{-j \omega n} $$

if $x[n]$ and $y[n]$ are energy signals, it follows directly that

$$\begin{align}
Y(e^{j \omega}) &= H(e^{j \omega}) \cdot X(e^{j \omega}) \\
\\
\Big|Y(e^{j \omega})\Big| &= \Big|H(e^{j \omega})\Big| \ \Big|X(e^{j \omega})\Big| \\
\\
\Big|Y(e^{j \omega})\Big|^2 &= \Big|H(e^{j \omega})\Big|^2 \ \Big|X(e^{j \omega})\Big|^2 \\
\\
S_{yy}(e^{j \omega}) &= \Big|H(e^{j \omega})\Big|^2 \ S_{xx}(e^{j \omega}) \\
\end{align}$$

---

but to show this for finite *power signals* is a little more difficult.  remember that for $y[n]$, $S_{yy}(e^{j \omega})$ continues to exist, even if the DTFT $Y(e^{j \omega})$ and $\Big|Y(e^{j \omega})\Big|^2$ do not.  and the convolution operation continues to exist with the same summation expression for power signals as with energy signals.

recall for *power signals*, the autocorrelation is:

$$\begin{align}
 R_{yy}[m] & = \big\langle y[n+m], y[n] \big\rangle \\
     & = \lim_{M \to +\infty} \frac{1}{2M+1} \sum\limits_{n=-M}^{+M} y[n+m] \cdot \overline{y[n]} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Sir, can you help me understand the $|G_i(e^({j/omega})|^2$ in the cited text. Is it a PSD?

Comment: you're not very patient, are you?

Comment: BTW, when i am done, i will deleting all of these comments of **mine** above.  i hope you also delete yours.

Comment: I am so sorry. I thought you were finished. And I am sorry for my lack of patience. I got stuck here while studying and my temper just fired up.

Comment: i need to make sure i get my little summations right.  i will return to this later.

Comment: Are you suggesting $|X(e^{j\omega})|^2$ can be both Energy or Power Density, depending on whether the $x(n)$ is an energy or power signal? Thanks for your answer. Please do continue until it's finished.

Comment: $\big|X(e^{j\omega})\big|^2$ is not an expression for the Power Spectral Density.  only $S_{xx}(e^{j\omega})$ is.

Answer (score 3):

In the cited text, $x[n]$ is not a signal, but a wide-sense stationary random process.

$P_x(e^{j\theta})$ is not the DTFT of $x[n]$, but the DTFT of the *autocorrelation* of the process $x$, and it is called *power spectral density*.

The autocorrelation $R_x[k]$ has units of power; in fact, $R_x[0]$ is the average power of the process.

The PSD, therefore, has units of power density (how power is distributed (in average) at different frequencies).

Comment: I never said $P_x(e^{j\omega})$ was the the DTFT of $x(n)$. I don't have problem understanding it.The problem is with $G_i(e^{j\omega})$. It's the DTFT of $g_i(n)$. $g_i(n)$ is not an auto-correlation sequence. Then, how come $|G_i(e^{j/omega})|^2$ is a PSD?? Thanks.

Comment: It's a shame to this - I don't know the difference between a random signal and a process (I am a beginner student). Can you give me a link where the difference between the two has been discussed? Thank you.

Comment: @Sadist_Tanmoy A *random process* is a collection of random variables. Usually this collection is indexed by "time" (which can be discrete or continuous). A *random signal* is a realization of a random process. I.e. if you were to sample your random process repeatedly, you'd get different random signals (which BTW will follow the statistics of the underlying random process).